# Xamarin System.Exception when adding Content page VS

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When trying to add a `Content Page` to the solution in visual studio, the following error occurs:

```
Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.

The project system has encountered an error.

Did not find new element in the hierarchy for item `Views\MyPage.xaml`.
The item would have been added with type "Page".
The project item schema service knows about this item type.
The item does exist in the project file.
```

When adding the file I do the following:

`Right click on Views in my Xamarin Solution > Add > New Item > Content Page > Add`

When looking in the windows explorer, there is a file created `MyPage.xaml` but it has not created `MyPage.xaml.cs` and it is not added to the solution

It is a blank Xamarin shared project and this error just keeps happening...

It's driving me nuts as I can't even add a single page

As a workaround, I add the files manually using the W. explorer and then edit app.projitems manually, but this is just ridiculous.

Comment: Mazzy, i've found anything in this site. Maybe helps you. `https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17661/issue-with-using-xaml-in-a-shared-xamarin-forms-project`. If doesn't help, i tried.

Comment: My 'solution' from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47920864/2953322 is basically just - add it with a different version of Visual Studio (I used VS 2015 to add it for a project in VS 2017). Not sure if this is an option for you; should be a bit quicker than editing the app.projitems...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did not find new element in the hierarchy for item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48889367/did-not-find-new-element-in-the-hierarchy-for-item)

Answer (score 6):

As a dirty workaround until this gets fixed, adding the files "manually" to the project gets the job done.

With Visual Studio closed,

1. copy/paste existing (working) *.xaml and *.xaml.cs files (rename
   them as you please)
2. open the newly pasted files with a text
   editor (not VS) and rename the contents to your chosen name in #1
3. add newly pasted files to your *.projitems file (open it in a text
   editor, search for the filenames you copied in #1 and add the new
   ones similarly) - there'll be 3 places to add them

Now open the solution in VS and rebuild - it should look and build fine.

Comment: I've spent a couple of hours trying to fix this, almost went as far as using .Net Standard, despite not needing it.  I eventually reverted to your external editor approach, created ten 'spare' forms then used macros in notepad++ to add them en-masse to the project file.  It really sux though.

Comment: The problem occurs in Standard .Net as well, so don't waste your time. Great idea with the macros - but I'll agree with you: this really sucks. It's such a basic necessity.

Comment: Is there any other visual studio setting to do this automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if you go into the VS2017 installer and install the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) development workload, this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Make sure  you have 
StackLayout 
instead of 
ContentPage.Content
in your .xaml files that throw this exception on VS.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A75Fo.png)

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.