# Xamarin Visual Studio 2017: Cannot Add Cross-Platform View Page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

So I use the Xamarin Cross-Platform application template. I want to add `LoginPage.xaml` view to my project. So I choose `add -> new item -> contentpage`.

There is always error:

> The project system has encountered an error:
>
> Did not find new element in the hierarchy for item
>   "Views\LoginPage.xaml". The item would have been added with type
>   "Page". The project item schema service knows about this item type.
>   The item does exist in the project file.

After I close the error. There is another error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Exception of type "System.Exception" was thrown.

Then what happenend next is the "LoginPage.xaml" file is created but not included in the project (it is hidden). I cannot include it in my project because it keeps refusing. There is no xaml.cs file created.

How can I fix this?

Comment: same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738138/xamarin-system-exception-when-adding-content-page-vs

Comment: did you got the solution? The above link not solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is officially "Under Investigation" (reported and answered: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/160939/bug-adding-xaml-content-page-to-shared-project-xam.html) and there is a workaround:

> a workaround is to install the Universal Windows Platform development workload

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do was actually add it in a different version of Visual Studio. I just happened to have both 2015 and 2017 installed. My VS 2015 didn't give me as many options for templates, so I ended up making content pages and later changing the markup to master or whatever I needed.
Just FYI, I've also found that sometimes I can add an XAML page, but it separates the .xaml and .xaml.cs instead of nesting them.