# Did not find new element in the hierarchy for item

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create a simple page for a Xamarin app but am completely unable to proceed with the most basic of steps. I check out the branch from the project repo, and attempt to add a new file. When I do so (Right clicking on folder, Add-> New Item->Content Page) I get this error:

[image: This Error]

It does actually create the .xaml file but not the `.xaml.cs` file to go with it. I first tried to manually create the cs file and associate it but ran into increasingly mysterious errors. Today I created them outside of VS before booting it up and both files are now present but with the dotted icon instead of a regular one and the cs file is not nested beneath the xaml file.

If I try to open my projitems file inside VS to make the association I am given the error "Specified method is not supported". If I choose to 'Open With', no screen ever pops up allowing me to choose. After this I closed down VS and edited the projitems file in notepad again and linked the xaml and cs file. This looked as though it worked but when I add it to the main `TabbedPage` with a simple `Children.Add(new MyReviews());` it is not recognized -> `The type or namespace name 'MyReviews' could not be found`.

These error happen if I make my own branch based on the master or try to add a new file to the master directly. No one else in the project is having these errors.

The only thing I really did differently from the rest is try to get the emulator working for android which apparently has a lot of compatibility issues and requires older versions of the xamarin plugins. I was not able to do this and ended up uninstalling and reinstalling everything twice since I didn't touch the installer software the first time and everything stuck.

Is anyone able to help me debug these issues or know why I am encountering so many at every turn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been in the exact same situation. As it turned out, the rest of my team had added Universal Windows Platform (UWP) support to their VS2017 install, and I hadn't. *Running the Visual Studio Installer and adding UWP fixed this issue completely.*

Of course, you might not need or want to include UWP support in any of your Xamarin apps (I didn't). It seems most likely that it's just one or two support assemblies that are mssing or wrong without the UWP support, but I haven't found the time or energy to figure out any more details.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! At a quick look it seems that did it. I guess I forgot, or chose not, to include the UWP during one of my reinstalls.